# How can I get highcharts Donut chart to auto calculate percentages

Tags: highcharts

How do I get the Donut chart in Highcharts to auto calculate the precentages of the data I sent . For example my data can be data: [50.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81] and I want to know how can the charts calculate the inner pie chart (of the Donut chart) to show or render as percentages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
this.percentage
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBkRj/):

```
dataLabels: {
     formatter: function() {
     return '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.percentage +'%';
     }
}
```

Api:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter